# Build fails with resolve errors

Tags: socket.io, svelte, nx-workspace

I am trying to setup socket.io-client inside a svelte component.

The docs say that I can do `import { io } from 'socket.io-client'`.

But when I try to run the app using the `serve` target, the command fails with the following logs:

```
Bundle complete. Watching for file changes...
Bundling...
'bufferutil' is imported by bufferutil?commonjs-external, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'utf-8-validate' is imported by utf-8-validate?commonjs-external, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
Circular dependency: node_modules\util\util.js -> node_modules\util\node_modules\inherits\inherits.js -> node_modules\util\util.js
Circular dependency: node_modules\util\util.js -> node_modules\util\node_modules\inherits\inherits.js -> C:\Users\munda\Documents\upwork\upwork-gameshow\node_modules\util\util.js?commonjs-proxy -> node_modules\util\util.js
@rollup/plugin-typescript: Rollup 'sourcemap' option must be set to generate source maps.
No name was provided for external module 'tty' in output.globals – guessing 'tty'
No name was provided for external module 'os' in output.globals – guessing 'os'
No name was provided for external module 'fs' in output.globals – guessing 'fs'
No name was provided for external module 'child_process' in output.globals – guessing 'require$$0'
No name was provided for external module 'http' in output.globals – guessing 'require$$1'
No name was provided for external module 'https' in output.globals – guessing 'require$$2'
No name was provided for external module 'net' in output.globals – guessing 'net'
No name was provided for external module 'tls' in output.globals – guessing 'tls'
No name was provided for external module 'crypto' in output.globals – guessing 'require$$0$3'
No name was provided for external module 'zlib' in output.globals – guessing 'zlib'
No name was provided for external module 'bufferutil' in output.globals – guessing 'require$$1$1'
No name was provided for external module 'stream' in output.globals – guessing 'require$$0$2'
No name was provided for external module 'utf-8-validate' in output.globals – guessing 'require$$0$1'
Creating a browser bundle that depends on Node.js built-in modules ("tty", "os", "http", "https", "zlib" and "stream"). You might need to include https://github.com/snowpackjs/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node
```

Steps I took to generate the app:

1. Initiate an nx-workspace using `yarn create nx-workspace`
2. Install the svelte generators using `yarn add @nxext/svelte`, link: [https://nx.dev/community#:~:text=the%20Nx%20workflow-,%40nxext/svelte,-Nx%20plugin%20to](https://nx.dev/community#:%7E:text=the%20Nx%20workflow-,%40nxext/svelte,-Nx%20plugin%20to)
3. Generate a `svelte` application using the installed generator.
4. Add the `socket.io` client side code in the component (basic socket initialisation as mentioned in docs).
5. Since my server and client are not going to be hosted on the same domain, add the `import { io } from 'socket.io-client'` and initialize the socket using `const socket = io(SERVER_URL)`(in my case this was http://localhost:3000)
6. Install socket.io client using `yarn socket.io-client`.
7. Run the `serve` target using `nx run-many --target=serve --all --parallel`, fingers crossed.

Result: The above mentioned log.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to install the following missing dependencies:

- `bufferutil`
- `utf-8-validate`

A simple `yarn add bufferutil utf-8-validate` fixed it for me. This is mentioned in [docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-installation/#:%7E:text=There%20are%202,by%20the%20spec.) for `socket.io-client` package or `socket.io` official documentation website.

This did fix builds on my PC (windows) but I could not get the same thing running on mac. I tried deleting `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, re-running `yarn`.

Finally I had to go through the CDN route.

This is how I did it:

1. Move the socket initialisation logic in a function.

```html
<script>
  ...
  const initialiseSocket = () => {
    socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('messages', (data) => {
      //...
    });
  }
</script>
```

2. Add a svelte:head tag to load the socket-io.client from CDN and pass the function to this script's `on:load`.

```html
<svelte:head>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.2.0/socket.io.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-PiBR5S00EtOj2Lto9Uu81cmoyZqR57XcOna1oAuVuIEjzj0wpqDVfD0JA9eXlRsj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    on:load={initialiseSocket}></script>
</svelte:head>
```